# Cannot login using email in cakephp, works good with username

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

I cannot login using email in CakePHP 2.1, when i try with username then its working perfectly good.

Below is the code

### View : login.ctp

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    //echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

### Controller : UsersController.php

```
<?php
    public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            if ($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid email and password'));
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

### Model : User.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class User extends AppModel {
    public function beforeSave(){
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])){
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

### Database Structure : users table

```
id Auto_Increment
username
email
password
role
```

I dont know, why it is not accepting any email id for login but for username its working good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) of the CakePHP book.

Here is the example from that section, you'll need to configure the form authentication to use a different field for the username.

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```